# elastic4s - create template with a given content

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I want to use the elastic4s api to delete and create templates.
I couldn't find an api to create a template with a given content, only create by providing a name.
Not sure how to use the IndexTemplateDsl.

Is this the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You create the template with a name, and then specifying the pattern match for that template, then you can add your mappings.

```
  val req = create template "my_template" pattern "matchme.*" mappings(
    mapping("sometype1").fields(
      stringField("field1"),
      geopointField("field2")
    ),
    mapping("sometype2").fields(
      stringField("field3"),
      intField("field4")
    )
  )
client.execute(req)
```

So it's very similar to creating a normal index.

Comment: Thanks! I already have the content available as json, is there a way to provide mappings a string that represent the mappings?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I could add that. Do you want something like mapping("mappingname") raw (yourjson)

Comment: That will be amazing!

Comment: @monkjack - mapping("mappingname") raw (yourjson) Is this functionality is there now in elastic4s-http?